# I want to use an iPhone5 S bought in the US in India

Tags: iphone

I bought an iPhone 5S from the US. It is unlocked. In India I am unable to use it with the local (Indian) service provider. When I insert a nano sim card, I am getting an error msg: "activation required".

Please explain how I could use it with local GSM service provider.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the "unlocked" iPhone 5S sold in the US is really unlocked for use on TMO or AT&T.  This means you need to activate it with one of those two carriers before it can be used with another carrier's SIM card.  I'd contact Apple to verify and see if they can do anything to help out since you're no longer in the US.

Comment: Factory unlocked phones work with any carrier. That's sort of the point.

Comment: Except Apple doesn't sell "factory unlocked" iPhones.  They sell an iPhone that's Unlocked for T-Mobile and AT&T use only.  Even T-Mobile's support site covers this issue:  https://support.t-mobile.com/thread/53528

Comment: From reading several other discussions and browsing Apple's website, Apple doesn't sell a "factory unlocked" iPhone 5S in the US.  Only the T-Mobile unlocked version.  You may have to activate the phone via iTunes with the original SIM card that shipped with the phone before you can swap out SIM cards.  I'd still contact Apple and ask them about the situation.

Comment: Apple most certainly sells factory unlocked iPhones: http://store.apple.com/ca/buy-iphone/iphone5s/32gb-space-grey-unlocked. They, however, do not sell unlocked devices in the US yet, but rather sell a version dubbed "T-Mobile contract-free", which they say "If you buy iPhone for T-Mobile, it will arrive with a nano-SIM card already installed that you can activate by visiting an Apple Retail Store or a T-Mobile store or by calling T-Mobile. When you travel internationally, you can use a nano-SIM card for iPhone 5s from a local GSM carrier" which is essentially unlocked.

Comment: And Apple starts selling true a unlocked iPhone 5s: http://www.macrumors.com/2013/11/22/apple-begins-offering-unlocked-sim-free-iphone-5s-models-in-u-s-with-1-2-week-shipping/